# Android listview repeats elements

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` that at that will dynamically populate based on an `arraylist`. I have a custom `arrayadapter` class defined. The list works exactly right except that when I rotate the screen from landscape to portrait the list repeats each element like 3 times. Here is the code for the `getView` function.

```
rows = (ListView)findViewByid(R.id.listview1);// in adapter constructor

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_slot,null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView, position);
    }
    else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.player_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.player_score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);
    holder.dec_score = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrement);
    holder.inc_score = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increment);
    holder.dec_score.setTag(holder);
    holder.inc_score.setTag(holder);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    Button dec = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrement);
    Button inc =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.increment);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView score = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);

    System.out.println("tag = " +dec.getTag());

    Player temp = getPlayer(position);
    System.out.println(temp.getPlayer_name() + temp.getPlayer_score());
    if(temp != null){
        //holder.player_name.setText(temp.getPlayer_name());
        //holder.player_score.setText(""+temp.getPlayer_score());
        name.setText(temp.getPlayer_name());
        score.setText(""+temp.getPlayer_score());
    }

    dec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int position =  rows.getPositionForView((View)v.getParent());
            Player temp = getPlayer(position);
            System.out.println("Player "+ temp.getPlayer_name() + "'s score changed");
            temp.setPlayer_score(temp.getPlayer_score()-score_increment);
            PlayerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }   
    });

    inc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        private Button dec;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int position =  rows.getPositionForView((View)v.getParent());
            Player temp = getPlayer(position);
            System.out.println("Player "+ temp.getPlayer_name() + "'s score changed");
            temp.setPlayer_score(temp.getPlayer_score()+score_increment);
            PlayerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help? this is frankly frustrating because I've looked at a lot of posts about it and mine seems to fit all of the answers. Also, I've just noticed, every switch from portrait to landscape and back to portrait produces two more repeats.

Comment: convertView.setTag(holder); <- This should go inside your if(convertView == null) statement. That's because, the convertView is a view that went off the screen, and is being recycled to make the view that just appeared on the screen. Because it's being recycled, it already has a holder. If convertView == null however, then the view does not have a holder.

Comment: well if it's there then it just sets the tag to the tag that it just found so yes that should be moved to avoid an unnecessary instruction but it does nothing for repeating elements. Thank your for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with the code. The manifest needed to be modified so that the activity doesn't refresh upon orientation change. By adding  `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity in the manifest it works perfectly.